# Why does this Powershell function return a list sometimes and an XmlElement other times?

Tags: xml, powershell

For some reason, the following Read-TestControllerXml powershell function returns an object of type System.Xml.XmlElement if my XML file only contains one computer node, but it returns a list (which is what I would always expect) if there are multiple computer nodes.

An example of the XML file is as follows:

```
<test_controller>
    <defaults>
        <nunit path='C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console.exe' />
        <nunit_results local_path='C:\Test_Results' remote_path='C:\Test_Results' />
        <powershell path='C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' />
        <psexec path='C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe' />
    </defaults>

    <platform os='windows' version='2012' cpu='x64'>
      <computer hostname='VM-2012R2-03' alias='standalone-01' configuration='standalone' image='VM-2012R2-03:Clean' />
    </platform>
</test_controller>
```

And here is the powershell function:

```
####################################################################
# Parses the TestController.xml file and returns a list of Computer XML objects.
#
# Syntax:
#     Read-TestControllerXml [-TestControllerXml] <path to TestController.xml> [<CommonParameters>]
#
# Returns:  An array of [Xml] nodes for each of the <computer> tags in TestController.xml.
####################################################################
function Read-TestControllerXml
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $TestControllerXml
    )

    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

    # Read the TestController XML configuration file
    $TestController = [xml] (Get-Content $TestControllerXml)

    Write-Verbose "Selecting computer nodes..."
    $computerNodes = $TestController.SelectNodes("//test_controller/platform/computer")
    Write-Verbose "Selecting default nodes..."
    $defaultNodes = $TestController.SelectSingleNode("//test_controller/defaults")

    $computers = @()

    foreach ($computerNode in $computerNodes)
    {
        Write-Verbose "***** Before adding default attributes *****"
        Write-Verbose "$($computerNode.OuterXml)"

        # Add default attributes to the node
        foreach ($dnode in $defaultNodes.ChildNodes)
        {
            if ($dnode.NodeType -eq "Comment") { continue } # Skip comments.

            # Search for the node items in the defaults section
            $cnode = $computerNode

            if ($dnode.Name -ne $computerNode.Name)
            {
                Write-Verbose "Selecting '$($dnode.Name)' nodes..."
                $cnode = $computerNode.SelectSingleNode($dnode.Name)
            }

            # Append the default nodes that do not exist in the computer specific sections  
            if ($cnode -eq $null)
            {
                Write-Verbose "*** cnode != null  cnode.OuterXml is: '$($cnode.OuterXml)'"
                Write-Verbose "Appending default '$($dnode.Name)' node that don't exist in the computer nodes..."
                $cnode=$computerNode.AppendChild($TestController.ImportNode($dnode, $true))
            }
            # Append the default attributes that do not exist in the computer specific sections  
            else
            {
                Write-Verbose "Appending default attributes that don't exist in computer nodes..."
                foreach ($attribute in $dnode.Attributes)
                {
                    if (-not $cnode.HasAttribute($attribute.Name))
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "Adding attribute '$($attribute.Name)=$($attribute.Value)' to the computer node."
                         $cnode.SetAttribute($attribute.Name, $attribute.Value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Write-Verbose "***** After adding default attributes *****"
        Write-Verbose "$($computerNode.OuterXml)"
        Write-Verbose "************************************************************"

        $computers += $computerNode
    }

    return $computers
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this similar question and the solution from there works:
[Function not returning expected object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121969/function-not-returning-expected-object)

i.e. changing:

```
return $computers
```

to:

```
return ,$computers
```

Comment: There is no reason to hate powershell. It was trying to do you a favour with one element. Your data was always ok!

Comment: You've got to remember that PowerShell is a `Shell scripting language` and is targeted primarily at system admins. Admins shouldn't have to worry about whether their function returns 0, 1 or N results in order for it to work in a pipeline.  That is, when a scalar value is put at the front of the pipeline, the pipeline is expected to process that single object.  When a value representing a collection is put at the front of a pipeline, the pipeline is expected to process `each individual object in the collection` and not the collection as a single object.

Comment: The comma trick simply wraps the array in another array so the individual object output by unrolling the array is the original array.  Note: in general this is not recommended for proper pipeline operation e.g. if I wanted to use your modified function I'm forced to do this `Read-TestControllerXml $xmlPath | Foreach {$_} | Foreach { ..do something with XmlElement.. }` instead of doing it more directly like so `Read-TestControllerXml $xmlPath | Foreach { ..do something with XmlElement.. }`

Answer (score 1):

I took your example function and sample data. Running the function I get the output you describe.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> (Read-TestControllerXml C:\temp\xml.txt).GetType().FullName
System.Xml.XmlElement
```

Then I add a computer node to the sample file and run the function again.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> (Read-TestControllerXml C:\temp\xml.txt).GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
```

This is correct since your function returns and array of objects. If you break down the items and check their type it should make sense.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> Read-TestControllerXml C:\temp\xml.txt | ForEach-Object{$_.GetType().FullName}
System.Xml.XmlElement
System.Xml.XmlElement
```

I had two items and put them into a ForEach-Object loop and check there type individually. Since your output is an array expect to have more than one object. In conclusion your function is always returning `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` just when there is more than one it is an `System.Object[]` array.

**For curiosity sake**

I tried to force $computers to be an array of xml elements like this `$computers = [System.Xml.XmlElement[]]@()`. It did not change the output. Multiple items are still outputted as a `System.Object[]`