# Powershell converts ArrayList to Array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a block which parses a list of files from S3 to get the file names.

```
$GetFileNamesByType = {
    Param(
        $fileType,
        $list
    )

    $entryList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($item in $list){
        if($item.Name.Contains($fileType)){
            $entryList.Add($item.Name) | Out-Null
        }
    }

    return $entryList
}
```

I call this method and it returns me the following list:

```
2016-08-31_21-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
2016-08-30_21-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
2016-08-30_22-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
2016-08-30_20-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
2016-08-31_23-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
2016-08-31_20-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
2016-08-30_23-15-17_server-1.1.20558_client-1.1.20518.zip
```

Howerver, what I don't understand is that when I check the list type, it is an array instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function not returning expected object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121969/function-not-returning-expected-object)

Comment: You can use `foreach` as an expression to generate a normal array faster than ArrayList: `return foreach ($item in $list) { if($item.Name.Contains($fileType)){$item.Name} }` Also, `return` is optional.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestion, the reason I am using ArrayList is that I need to remove the elements in it dynamically. Maybe I should try LinkedList but if it still returns Array, I have to find a workaround.

Comment: Convert the normal array produced via foreach expression to arraylist in the end: `[Collections.ArrayList]$entryList` and it'll be still faster! Well, not by much though.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah, thanks!! It didn't occur me before :)